Ubuntu 24.04.1 client device login an active directory error
my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS has a problem
i joined the device to an active directory and it completed with success,
but when i log out and try to login again it tells me wrong password and failed to authenticate.
the time settings are synced with timesynced package.
when l unplugged the ethernet cable it login successfully.
i've tried a few changes to the sssd.conf and pam session files.
but the problem kept happening less frequently only but didn't disappear.
any help ?
